# conditional short hand doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

```
var countChecked = $('.member_checkbox:checked').length;
$('.email-btn').text('Email ' + countChecked + 'member' + countChecked > 1 ? 's');
```

What's wrong with my conditional short hand above? The logic I want is add 's' if the count is more than 1 to the string.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "conditional short hand". It's the ternary operator, and it needs **three** operands, hence "ternary".

Comment: `...> 1 ? 's' : ''`, but that still messes up zero, so you want `...!=1?'s':''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes **three operands**. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

You're not using it with correct syntax.

The syntax is

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

You've missed the else part of the [conditional/ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
$('.email-btn').text('Email ' + countChecked + 'member' + (countChecked > 1 ? 's' : ''));
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, wrap the conditional part inside parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of Conditional Short hand is
**condition ? expr1 : expr2**

In your expression,
**Condition** is $('.email-btn').text('Email ' + countChecked + 'member' + countChecked > 1
**Expr 1** is 's'
**Expr 2 is Not Given**

Also,
What does 's' means, is it assigned to something?

Comment: "s" is a string added to "member" to make it become "members"

Answer (score 0):

```
var countChecked = $('.member_checkbox:checked').length;
$('.email-btn').text('Email ' + countChecked + 'member' + ((countChecked > 1) ? 's' : ''));
```

Conditional statement needs to be in the brackets and do provide the else part if you don't want to append anything in this case just append ''.